# Json : Content Parsing error

Tags: java, json

I have json file like this

```
[
     {

       "topic": "Example1", 
       "ref": {
            "1": "Example Topic", 
            "2": "Topic"
        }, 
       "contact": [
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "corresponding": true, 
                "name": "XYZ"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "name": "ZXY"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "name": "ABC"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1, 
                    2
                ], 
                "name":"BCA"
            }
        ] , 

        "type": "Presentation"
     }
]
```

I want to parse the `ref` array. I tried this. But showing error.

```
jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getJSONArray("ref").getJSONObject(index).toString()
```

Now my question is

1) What is the correct way to parse that array's content.

Comment: There are many `ref` in this JSON; Which one do you want?

Comment: @JBNizet"ref": {
            "1": "Example Topic", 
            "2": "Topic"
        }

Comment: When you're just learning, especially, *do not* "daisy-chain" operations together like that.  Make each method call a separate statement and assign the result to a temp (which is then used in the next statement).  This makes it much easier to debug and easier to edit when you discover you need to rearrange things.

Comment: And go to json.org to see the (very simple) JSON syntax spec.  It takes all of 5 minutes to learn, and knowing it makes processing JSON *much* easier.

Answer (score 3):

The whole JSON is an array (starts with `[`). Its first element is an object (starts with `{`). This object has an attribute "ref". Its value is an object (starts with `{`).

So, to get this object, you need

```
jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getJSONObject("ref")
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it By

```
 JSONObject arJS = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getJSONObject("ref");
 for(int counter = 1 ; jo<=jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getJSONObject("ref").length();counter++){

               String value = arJS.getString(String.valueOf(counter));

           }
```